# Looking for a Fax gateway with PHP API

Tags: php, fax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I send a fax using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301810/can-i-send-a-fax-using-php)

I need a FAX gateway PHP API for my website.

I have a script that generates a report for a Customer and then it will be sent to the spcified Fax Nr. provided by the customer.

Comment: Please always specify which country you are in and which countries faxes need to go to

Answer (score 0):

As shown ablve, this is a duplicate, but here was the main answer (by: Douwe Maan):

As fax is not internet-based like email, there is no easy way to do this, like you can send emails using mail().

You can, though, use PHP to talk to an internet fax service, as described here: http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/php