# How can i send fax using hylafax php?

Tags: php, fax

How can i send fax using `hylafax php`? Is there any `php` class to do this? i searched 1 full day in google to get a class. but didn't get a simple function
please give me link to download a `php` class.

Comment: please help me to find a class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301810/can-i-send-a-fax-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute hylafax's sendfax command from PHP using PHP's shell_exec() command.  Ex:

```
<?
   $ok=shell_exec("sendfax -n -d 5551212 /etc/passwd");
?>
```